# Editing a theme's templates

Tags: customization

I have installed the template successfully. I know how to work with modules and articles and menu creation. I don't know how to work with code parts.

- How can I change the styles on css.
- How to modify the template
- How to modify the home page

I have tried many times finding the folder on the installation directory but couldn't. How can I find it and change it.

Comment: Are you running a WordPress.com site? In that case: this StackExchange is not meant for WordPress.com questions. If not, could you remove the wordpress.com tag :-)?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions here. We have a one question per post policy. Please split your question into multiple well constructed questions. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Where is theme located is a little tricky to answer in very general form:

1. Themes are detected in the registered theme directories (which can be multiple folders).
2. Typically there is at least one theme folder in site's content folder (however content folder is also configurable).

However, for typical out of the box install this is simple enough with defaults of `wp-content/themes` inside the WordPress folder.